# How to convert ascii to hex in 24bits c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert ascii to hex in 96bit or 128bit. Because the ascii is not fix, it may like "ABCDE12345" or "ABCDEF123456". So how to convert it to hex? As this is RFID encoding, so the hex needs to be in 96 or 128. Currently get some sample code online as below:

```
  public static string ASCIIToHex(string ascii)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ascii))
            {
                byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ascii);

                foreach (byte b in inputBytes)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("{0:x2}", b));
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString().ToUpper();
        }
```

Comment: Just pad with 0s.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about padding will solve my issue. =)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, or what you mean by "some of ASCII is 11 bits". It would really help if you'd provide sample input and sample output.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use it.

```
    uint value;
    if (!uint.TryParse(label16.Text, 
           System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out value)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid hex value");
        return;
    }
    serialPort1.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, 3);
```

Comment: This answer seems unrelated to the question. This appears to be trying to *parse* hex and write it to a serial port, whereas the OP is trying (I think; it's unclear) to *format* some data as text, with no labels or serial ports involved.